# terraform google_compute_instance - set variables instead of static labels

Tags: terraform

i'm trying to set variable in the key section of the labels when
creating `google_compute_instance`

this is possible:

```
labels {
    "billing-zone"          = "${var.zone}"
  }
```

but this:

```
labels {
    "${var.zone}"          = ""
  }
```

is not. ( the var can be only in the value section )
is there anyway to pass that?

Thank you.

Comment: did you try    `"${zone}"          = ""` (https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/2042#issuecomment-104724603)

Comment: it's not working, and mine is a bit different its in the labels and not in the tags